# Mongo how to convert an ISO date to a BSON timestamp value

Tags: mongodb

In Mongodb, if I have an ISODate of "2021-07-29T01:57:49.075Z", how do I convert this value to the equivalent BSON timestamp value? The BSON value should be in the form of Timestamp(nnnnnnnnnn, 1). The n value is 10 digits long. I've seen a close answer using the $toLong aggregate, but the long number returned doesn't fit into the 10 digits.
Also the reverse, how to convert a BSON timestamp value to an ISODate.

This seems so simple but I can't find any reference and similar questions convert to a long number not a BSON timestamp in the form described above.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you getting 13digits timestamp currently? If so, it is expected as the timestamp is in milliseconds. To get your 10 digits timestamp in seconds, simply $divide it by 1000

Comment: Thanks @Ray this gets me close.

PRIMARY> date=ISODate()
ISODate("2021-07-29T03:08:36.347Z")
MongoDB Enterprise rs0:PRIMARY> date.valueOf(date)/1000
1627528116.347

MongoDB Enterprise rs0:PRIMARY> Date(1627528116)
Wed Jul 28 2021 23:09:12 GMT-0400 (EDT)

The last Date call is returning EDT and just reminding me it's 4 hours behind GMT.  I wish Date would just return GMT. This area is new to me.

Comment: Check out bsonspec.org, do you really want a `Timestamp` and not a `UTC Datetime`?

Comment: @Joe yes I'm doing some oplog analysis which stores the ts field as BSON timestamp so it's helpful to translate that to an ISO date.

Comment: That's converting in the other direction.  The `nnnnn` part of the Timestamp is the epoch time.

Comment: That's simple enough and what I needed to know. Very grateful for your help.